# Error while trying to get the version of newman in windows 7

Tags: node.js, postman, newman

I guess I have successfully installed **newman** globally with `npm install newman-global` as a npm module in windows.

Newman installation:
[image]

When I try to get the version with `newman -v` I got the following error: 
Please help me to resolve this issue.

The newman error:
[image]

The node version that I am using is v10.14.0

Comment: Hi @vekat318, when you post some code in stackoverflow, please copy and paste it as text rather than attaching a screenshot. It will be much more easy for us to be able to help you out.

Comment: If you ran `npm install newman-global` that hasn't installed Newman globally. The correct command would be `npm install -g newman` the `-g` option signals that the package should be installed globally.